# After migration can`t update product image

Tags: magento2, admin, product-images, migration

I **migrated**  Magento from **1.9.0.1 to 2.2.5.**
After this migration I can't add **new image** for some products
Could you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Anybody were able to fix this issue. We are facing exactly the same issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/151273)

Answer (score 0):

The image directory path should have already been carried over from your 1.9.X installation. all you should have to do to add the images back is copy over your media/ directory on your old installation into pub/media/ in your new installation.

from here flush your cache and re deploy your static content and your images should appear:

rm -rf pub/static && php-7.0 bin/magento cache:clean && php-7.0 bin/magento cache:flush

php-7.0 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: I haven't problem with old images, I couldn't add new image from admin panel

Comment: ah, i see now.. what is happening when you try to upload images?

Comment: when I upload new image it showing with other images. but when I click on "save" button - magento say "You saved the product." but image not added to product

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well. Did you manage to find a solution to this?